# platform of the target `fubarTests` (iOS 4.3) is not compatible with `Kiwi (2.2.1)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 5.0

Tags: ios, cocoapods, kiwi

I can't seem to get past this error and don't know why.
I'm running xcode 4.6.3
The project's ios deployment target says iOS 6.1
the base sdk is 6.1

My Podfile is:

```
# Podfile
platform :ios  
target :fubarTests, :exclusive => true do 
 pod 'Kiwi' 
end
```

and when I try to run pod install from the command line I get the error about the target being iOS 4.3.

Why does it think my target is 4.3 and how can I change it?

Comment: You might want to check your version of CocoaPods. `pod --version` should return `0.24.0` otherwise you'll probably want to update with `[sudo] gem update` (newer version of CocoaPods automatically detect your project's version so you don't have to specify the platform as Adam suggested)

Comment: @KeithSmiley wow that's a nice addition, I wasn't aware that had been added.

Answer (score 23):

You need to specify

```rb
platform :ios, '6.1'
```

Answer (score 9):

It's no longer necessary to specify the platform and version. For me I just deleted the line beginning `platform` and everything started working.

Comment: But then the cocoapods won't tell you if a pod is not compatible with your ios version.... and maybe your app is going to crash or you just can't use the framework