# Cocoapods user-install: cannot run pod command

Tags: cocoapods

I have installed Cocoapods on OS X Mavericks using the `--user-install` option (to avoid having to use `sudo` for the installation) following the instructions at http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started . I have also created a `.profile` file in my home directory with the following:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/gems
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Cocoapods successfully installs, but I am unable to run the `pod` command.

When running it from the command line it says `No such file or directory`. From what I understand, it should be installed into the `/Users/me/gems/bin` folder. However, this folder does not exist at all - the only Ruby related folder in my home directory is `/Users/me/.gem`.

I have tried running `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod` but that results in the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from .gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:14:in `<main>'
```

...but from what I understand, I shouldn't be running it from that location directly.

Any assistance for a Cocoapods newbie appreciated!

Comment: Very helpful and still applicable as of 10.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after a lot of research and trying different things I have managed to get this working. I am not quite sure what eventually fixed the problem, or whether it was a combination of things, but for anyone else encountering this same problem here's what I did:

1. Installed the Xcode command line tools for Mavericks. The option to install this is no longer available in Xcode 5, so you need to download them from https://developer.apple.com/downloads . Some people seem to say they are already installed as part of Xcode 5 from the Mac App Store, whereas others say you need to manually install them. Either way, I figured that installing them again won't hurt.
2. The error message above talked about not being able to load `bundler/setup`. So, I (re?)installed the bundler ruby gem `gem install bundler --user-install`. Interestingly, when I then attempted to run the `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod` command again I got a different error: `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/Gemfile not found`.
3. What was really handy is that after the installation of `bundler` a message appeared saying `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run`. So, I checked out the contents of that folder and it contains the `pod` executable! Adding it to the PATH would certainly be handy, but I just ran it directly with the full path (after changing to my Xcode project folder containing the `Podfile`): `/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/pod install` and it all works!

When I ran `pod install` for the first time it showed a message saying `Setting up CocoaPods master repo` and stayed there for quite some time - I thought it had actually hung. However, it eventually completed. If you are unsure whether it is doing anything, or has hung, do `ls -la ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/.git/objects/pack/` and look at the time modified/size of the file it is downloading (thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022638/pod-install-is-staying-on-setting-up-cocoapods-master-repo#comment31804907_21022989) for the hint).

Another tip for new players - when I tried to install a pod (in my case, BlocksKit) I got a message saying `[!] The platform of the target Pods (iOS 4.3) is not compatible with BlocksKit (2.1.0) which has a minimum requirement of OS X 10.7 - iOS 5.0.` This was a surprising message, since my project targets iOS 7.0. Apparently you [don't need to specify the platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20922422/257314) anymore, so I entirely removed the platform line from the `Podfile` and it all works.

Hope that this helps other people just getting started with CocoaPods!

Comment: Short version: **pod** is located in ~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/ . Either reference it directly in your command or add it to the path

Answer (score 3):

After installing Mavericks, I got error with already installed cocoapods. So I ran this command to install the new updated cocoapods version, and it works now.

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: OP specified that they used the --user-install option, which is used when you can't/won't use sudo

Answer (score 3):

add:

export COCOAPODS_NO_BUNDLER=1

to your .zprofile or .bash_profile

Comment: Not sure if this solution helps with the problem OP is having. However, it helped me with a `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/Gemfile not found` found error. Actually the documentation `https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html#rubygems` gave me the clue that this solution might work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the pointers in these answers, I found that the [instructions for installing CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) provided on the CocoaPods web site are incorrect, regarding the contents of the `.profile` file, specifically the path.

As Skoota noted in the question, the path `$GEM_HOME/bin` does not exist. A comment by Videre gives the important clue: the correct path is `$GEM_HOME/ruby/2.0.0/bin`.

The correct `.profile` contents, which works for me at least, is:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

It is also worth noting that you must quit and relaunch the Terminal application for changes to the `.profile` file to take effect.

Comment: thanks man! changing my path variable from $GET_HOME/bin to $GET_HOME/ruby/{version}/bin worked!

Answer (score 1):

I use homebrew to install cocapods

First install homebrew (paste this code in terminal and hit enter)

```
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Second enter this

```
$ brew install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I ran into very similar problems. None of the above helped me so maybe others could benefit from my process.

1. Eventually just ran `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`, deleting everything that I did before.
2. Followed the steps for creating the `.profile` file
3. For good measure, closed Terminal and rebooted everything.
4. Ran `gem install cocoapods` which somehow didn't run into errors this time
5. Checked the install by running `gem which cocoapods` which fortunately returned the correct path
6. ran `pod setup` which didn't raise any errors again .

Not entirely sure what actually worked and what didn't but maybe someone will find this useful.